# How to run a specific method when props changes in Svelte3?

Tags: svelte-3

I'm building an autocomplete text field component. We will show popup of items filtered based on what users type. It is going to be async, I will get the details from the server and do some filtering based on the text typed in the field.

So here, I have run this filtering logic whenever I send new data to the component.

I come from angular, there we used to have ngOnChange(). Is there something similar available in svelte3.

Right now, I'm filtering by calling the method from outside by binding bind:this. I don't feel like this is a correct approach.

https://github.com/manojp1988/svelte3-autocomplete/blob/master/dev/App.svelte

Answer (score 4):

### Without stores, using a prop

Just using a prop:

```
export let search = '';
....
$: if (search !== '') {       // make it react to changes (in the parent)
     doSomeThing(search);
   };
```

### Stores

Svelte also has [stores](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores). A store is an observable object which can be observed everywhere even beyond you project with RxJS.
Example:

```
const unsubscribe = search.subscribe(s) => {
  doSomeThing(s);
}); 
onDestroy(unsubscribe);
```

In another component you can use search.set('Hi');

But looking forward for other solutions to handle these kind of changes in parent <-> child components or calling child Component methods.

From child to parent we can fire events.
But from parent to child ...? we can use a store or Component bind:this or ..? but ....